# Google Play isn't accepting high-res icon although it is 512x512 and 32-bit RGBA

Tags: android, image, google-play-services, png, google-play-console

Why won't my high-res icon upload in Google Play Console?

I am trying to change the high-res icon for my Android app "Surakarta". I have checked other Q/As on this site and other sites as well, but those don't answer my problem. That is because I am totally sure that my PNG image is 512x512 and 32-bit RGBA.

[image: Surakarta new high-res icon]

On using `file file_name`, I will get this output:

```
file_name: PNG image data, 520 x 520, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

I wonder what the problem could be. I created the image in LibreOffice Draw (the grid, and loops, e.g. the board) and then edited the vector (.svg) image in GIMP (added the shadows and pebbles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Image has 520x520 pixels. As you mentioned GooglePlay only accepts Images with 512x512 pixels.

Try this one that I resized for you:

[image: Google Play Icon]

Comment: OMG, I was so stressed that day, I couldn't see 512 vs 520. Even in the question, I copied 520x520 as output. This is a waste question - should I delete it? Thanks so much, for making me realize that.